# Adding values with Python to Mysql using raw_input

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python

What is wrong with this code?
I want to add values ​​to my Mysql database using raw input, but I can't do it.
The program runs perfectly, but when I look into database in mysql none of the data was recorded.

```
import MySQLdb

# Establecemos la conexión con la base de datos
bd = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","wil","1234","caras" )

# Preparamos el cursor que nos va a ayudar a realizar las operaciones con la base de datos
cursor = bd.cursor()

# Preparamos el query SQL para insertar un registro en la BD

sql = "INSERT INTO PERSONAS USUARIO VALUES" + raw_input("USUARIO: ")
sql = "INSERT INTO PERSONAS CONTRASENHA VALUES" + raw_input("CONTRASENHA: ")
sql = "INSERT INTO PERSONAS NOMBRE VALUES raw_input" + raw_input("NOMBRE: ")
sql = "INSERT INTO PERSONAS APELLIDO VALUES raw_input" + raw_input("APELLIDO: ")
sql = "INSERT INTO PERSONAS EDAD VALUES raw_input" + raw_input("EDAD: ")
sql = "INSERT INTO PERSONAS SEXO VALUES raw_input" + raw_input("SEXO: ")
sql = "INSERT INTO PERSONAS SALARIO VALUES raw_input" + raw_input("SALARIO: ")

try:
   # Ejecutamos el comando
   cursor.execute(sql)
   # Efectuamos los cambios en la base de datos
   bd.commit()
except:
   # Si se genero algún error revertamos la operación
   bd.rollback()

# Nos desconectamos de la base de datos 
bd.close()
```

Comment: "What is wrong with this code?" Erm, most everything. Please review additional tutorials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you're replacing the `sql` variable content in each assigment, so only the last query will be executed. I also guess this is what you're trying to do:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO PERSONAS VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
               (raw_input("USUARIO: "), raw_input("CONTRASENHA: "),
                raw_input("NOMBRE: "), raw_input("APELLIDO: "),
                raw_input("EDAD: "), raw_input("SEXO: "),
                raw_input("SALARIO: ")))
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change "sql = " to "sql +=" from the second line and give ";" at end of all the statements. You are basically replacing all the query with the next one. Not adding to the string.